# Check a constraint after adding a Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key

If I add a foreign key constraint with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE [abc]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_some_col]
   FOREIGN KEY([some_col_id]) REFERENCES [xyz] ([some_col_id])
```

Is there any reason or advantage to follow it with this line?

```
ALTER TABLE [abc] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_some_col]
```